# C, How to find the index location of all instances of a character in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a string in C.  I want to get the index location of all instances of that character in the string.

It occurs more than one time so I need to return the index of all characters.

Example would be the string `str1` containing: `Banana`.  The character 'a' is found in index locations:  1, 3, 5

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use a loop using the string index as the loop variable. In the body, append the current index to the output array if the current character matches.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just something like this?

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
  if (str[i] == ch)
      location[index++] = i;
```

Comment: I had the same code but for some reason I thought it won't work (It's a big program so I don't compile it yet). Thank you very much and sorry for the dumb question :P

Comment: @user3147306 "I thought it won't work" -- why? "I don't compile it yet" - if it really is big (I doubt it would be really big...), you can just split it into multiple files and compile one after another. Also, if you don't compile your program, then you are doing it wrong -- how do you **test** if it works?

Comment: You could do a tiny bit more efficiently by not computing `strlen` first, but instead doing the null check as you go along.

Answer (score 0):

`strstr()` would help.

for details you can ref below.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: I know strstr but I'm not allowed to use pointers :(
I need a code to put it into a function which I wrote :P

Comment: @H2CO3 user3147306 might mean that he's required to use indices into an array rather than pointers.